# custom footer module for opencart v1.5.2.1

Tags: module, opencart

I am using latest version of opencart ( 1.5.2.1 ) but unable to add custom footer module. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You might want preserve Opencart default template, thus it's better copy the parts you need to modify (default/common/footer.tpl in your case), under (to say) your_template/common/footer.tpl and select from admin `your_template` for your store. This way you reduce changes and simplify upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit \catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\footer.tpl for all your needs.

Comment: It is suggested that you do not edit the default, but rather create your own template/theme (it's trivial).

Comment: http://demo.harnishdesign.net/opencart/ustore/    Check the custom footer module ( Facebook, Twitter, About etc ) in this site. I want like this.. I know about footer.tpl what to edit....check the admin of this live site. Please help me if you having any solutions.

Comment: @ Shakti If you want one like that just type into google: Facebook widget or look at http://www.facebook.com/badges/.  They will give you code that you just cut and paste into your footer.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy catalog\view\theme\default

Then rename the new default file to Your Store.

Then go in and change whatever files you want in the new theme.

Now you have a template to work from, and if you screw anything up, all the files are in original state back in the original default folder.

Answer (score 0):

I created successfully..Need to modify footer.tpl and footer.php file.